# Spring boot file corrupted on download

Tags: java, spring-boot, base64

I have different types of files stored and I have a controller to download the files. The files are stored in base64 and I'm trying to download the file and the file seems to be corrupted althought the download works. I could really use some pointers to fix my problem.

Here is what I have so far.

```
@GetMapping("/attachments")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getAttachment() {
    String file = "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";
    String decoded = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(file.getBytes()));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    InputStream targetStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(decoded, "UTF-8");

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(decoded.length())
                                                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream")).body(new InputStreamResource(targetStream));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base 64 encoded file is a PNG file. PNG files are binary files and cannot be represented as string and are not UTF-8 encoded. Just return the byte array.

```
@GetMapping("/attachments")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAttachment() {
    String file = "iVBORw0KG ... 5CYIIA";
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(file);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

    ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.builder("attachment")
        .filename(fileName).build();
    headers.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
        .contentLength(decoded.length)
        .body(decoded);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly for different file types too